# What's the fastest way to turn a triangular face into three quads?

Tags: modeling

What's the fastest way to turn a triangular face into three quads?[image]

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Subdivide triangle. Select face of middle triangle. Repeat. Select inner vertices and use <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>M</kbd> to merge at centre.

My 5 cents. What's yours?

[image]

p.s. no need to go into vertex mode. Face select and <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>M</kbd> is enough.

Comment: It is also possible to: Select triangle in middle -> Poke Face -> Select All -> Tris to Quads

Answer (score 17):

### Subdivision Surface modifier with Simple mode

Just add to your object a subdivision surface modifier from the list and choose the **Simple** option.

[image]

This method is obviously not good if you would like to subdivide only a subset of faces of your object as the modifier is being applied to the whole object (in this case made of a single face).

Comment: Still a nice one...

Comment: This is actually the best solution I have seen so far, only requires like three button presses

Answer (score 10):

I guess you could always use the shortcut and not model it all. :)

The Add Mesh Extra Objects Add-On has been updated in version 2.79 and now includes a triangle object. It is found under *Add Mesh>Math Function>Triangle*. There are options for 3 and 6 quad faces, and 3 tri faces.

If you do not have it enabled already, just enable it in user preferences with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> and search for 'extra'.

[image]

Here is an example gif:

[image]

Answer (score 5):

@Carlo presented the perfect solution IMO- the fastest one indeed. Here are my 5 cents though:

Subdivide the triangle with <kbd>W</kbd>-->*Subdivide*, then inset faces with <kbd>I</kbd> and input the proper scale value to place all the vertices in the center of the object. Press <kbd>W</kbd>-->*Remove Doubles*. Finally select some edges and get rid of them with <kbd>X</kbd>-->*Limited Dissolve*.
[image]

Comment: That's also nice. Tris to Quads also works as last step, btw.

Answer (score 2):

**Bmesh script**

[image]

- Checks selected element is tri.
- Removes tri face.
- Bisects the edges.
- Make edges from bisect verts to tri's median centre.
- Fill new edges and bisect edges  with contextual create (akin to <kbd>F</kbd>)

Select triangle face in edit mode run script.

```
import bpy
import bmesh

context = bpy.context
ob = context.edit_object
me = ob.data
bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(me)

tri = bm.select_history.active
# poll .. do we have a tri
if isinstance(tri, bmesh.types.BMFace) and len(tri.verts) == 3:
    edges = tri.edges[:]

    c = tri.calc_center_median()
    bm.faces.remove(tri)
    ret = bmesh.ops.bisect_edges(bm, edges=edges, cuts=1)
    verts = ret['geom_split'][:3]
    c = bm.verts.new(c)
    geom = ret['geom_split'][3:] +  [bm.edges.new([c, v]) for v in verts]  
    bmesh.ops.contextual_create(bm, geom=geom)
    bmesh.update_edit_mesh(me)
```