# Curve a Straight Line?

Tags: bezier-curves

Is there a way to "curve" a straight line?  In AutoCAD it was a very simple process.  I cannot though find a way to just take a straight line in Blender 2.8 and make it curved between the two vertices?

[image]

Comment: At the moment, the answer to this looks like: 1. Create a Bezier curve  2. in Edit mode, all selected, hit 'V','V'.  3. Hit 'V' again, > Auto, and manipulate control points. But if you're looking for something more specific, could you elaborate?

Comment: You could help us by including a screenshot. By "line", do you mean an edge connecting two polygons, a bezier curve, a NURBS curve... ?

Comment: Updated.  I want to take the line shown by the blue arrow that I have selected and curve it to approximately the curve of the red line.

I could take and subdivide it and pull each individual subdivision node to where it needs to be but that seems tedious and I'm sure there is a quicker way.

Comment: An edge is a straight line between two vertices.  To make a curve will involve subdividing of some form.  Proportional edit lets you move one vert and have others in given vicinity drop off in a regular (eg spherical manner).  https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/3dview/object/editing/transform/control/proportional_edit.html#edit-mode

Comment: Gotcha.  So there is no easy way (other than subdividing possibly) to just add an arc to an already existing line?

Comment: To clarify by way of example, to convert one edge on the default cube to curve.  Subdividing just that edge, and by some method arranging in an arc, will lead to 2 ngons (faces sharing original edge).  Would that result be Ok?  [Maybe Somewhat related](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/133880/15543)

Comment: I think what you’re running into is that AutoCAD can have actual circular arcs, trivially, and blender cannot.  Different conceptual models.  But I’m a total newbie so don’t take my word for it; maybe @RobinBetts can confirm?

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to use the spin tool to create a curved connection
[image]