# How to add this primitive to the Primitives menu in Blender

Tags: modeling

Can anyone please tell me how to add/install this script:

[How can I create a mathematically correct arc/circular segment?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/133870/how-can-i-create-a-mathematically-correct-arc-circular-segment)

into Blender 2.83? I have opened the file named **operator_mesh_add.py** in the folder **blender-2.83.0-linux64/2.83/scripts/templates_py/** and added the code there, but after restarting Blender there's no added entry in the primitives menu.

I have looked everywhere online for a script to make true arcs in Blender but this is the only one that (judging by the animated gif on the referenced page) seems to work in the way I am used to making them, as in SketchUp; draw begin point, then draw end point, then set the distance.

I'd appreciate any help!

Comment: This is a longstanding issue which still seemingly has no solution. People have been requesting a feature for some time to add custom primitives. But there is no way to do it in the UI and, apparently, it doesn't seem to work when trying to do it through scripting either, as you've discovered. One  workaround would be to have a blend file at the ready with your custom primitives in it, ready to be appended. Not ideal, I know.

Comment: @R-800 It is possible, but it as to be implemented as add-on. The script in question is missing the `bl_info` for this to work and it would have to be installed through *Edit > Preferences > Add-ons*. The `templates_py` is for the script templates in the text editor, so this is not the directory for a manual installation.

Comment: Yes. You are correct. Nevertheless, the fact remains that it is entirely too challenging to add custom primitives to Blender.

Comment: Thanks for the responses but really all I would like to do is run this script so I can draw an arc with specific parameters. I did discover that 'Text editor' is actually a Blender feature, so I copied the script, pasted it in there, saved it, and then ran the script which did create an arc in my model but I could not modify any parameters as in the animated gif shown on the page I referenced in my first post. Can anyone confirm this script works in Blender 2.83 and if so how? Or should I ask that on the aforementioned page I referenced?