# Arc Tool / Precise drawing / CAD Style

Tags: modeling

Is there a way to draw an **arc**, a portion of a circle, on an inclined face, with a very good precision on number (and position) of segments ? >> See gif (sorry in French)

I'm trying to learn Blender. As a Sketchup user, there are lots of things that seem very complicated to reproduce in Blender. I know this is not the same modeling philosophy, but these things are for me very important to reproduce. I precise that I'm a "precision freak" ;-)

I know Construction Lines Add on, but the arc tool just propose start-end-height options (no center).

Thanks !

[image]

Comment: Hi :). Perhaps the TinyCAD addon shipped with Blender could help?

Comment: Thanks, I don't know Tiny CAD ... i'll check
(I just know "Construction Lines")

Comment: Tiny CAD won't do what you're looking for.  Blender's not very good at CAD.

Comment: Somewhat related. https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/133870/how-can-i-create-a-mathematically-correct-arc-circular-segment