# How to extrude a curve from a triangle - Blender 2.93

Tags: mesh, bezier-curves, vertices, bevel, 2d

I'm trying to do the red marked shape on a triangle plane.

I do not know how to do that, nor what I have to search in order to learn how to do it.

I've been looking for an answer on the Internet, no luck yet.

---

I'm super new to blender, I could do basic stuff with 3DS Max but I just don't get Blender's workflow.

Thank you very much.

---

[image: What I want to do]

Comment: Could this be a duplicate of this topic?

https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/133870/how-can-i-create-a-mathematically-correct-arc-circular-segment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible solution is to activate the Tiny CAD add-on, where you can define a circle by three points.

[image: circle]

Comment: Thanks for the posts. This is not a regular forum, according to site rules [links to answers are not answers](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2382) if the link goes missing your answer becomes an empty shell without content. Answers should be substantial and stand on their own without relying on external data like links, videos or images. Instead of having users go through external links, either transcribe essential parts of the process here, linking the source, or posts these in the comments section instead.

Comment: FWIW, Tiny CAD addon is included with Blender, just activate it.

Comment: Thank you, I modified the answer accordingly

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I think this is the solution since it solves it at a certain steps.
I still need to join the created circle (semi-circle) to the triangle.
In origin I wanted to modify somehow the triangle's hypotenuses and make a circle. As I said on the post I still don't know Blender's workflow, so I guess this is what I need to go with.

Comment: To join the two geometries, you can either do a boolean operation (union) or simply press CTRL+J to merge them. And I'm not sure what you call hypotenuses as it's not a right triangle.

Comment: Hello, @AlexBarra, I think Jag's comment above can be read absolutely at face-value, without any intent to offend. Different folks from different cultures and with different first languages can interpret tone very differently, too.. I think,  assume the best, unless contrary evidence is very clear.

Comment: Definitely. I'm very sorry if it was taken as an offense. I was just trying to clarify the base case. Actually I don't even understand which part was deemed offensive.

Comment: Btw 'right' triangle means triangle with a 90° angle. Not a 'proper' triangle.