# How to fill a triangular shape with quads?

Tags: modeling

I need to be able to make these verticies fill with quads and still maintain it's curve. How might one go at this?
[image: Help!]

Comment: Hello and welcome :). I can't post a full answer now, but there's a function called [Grid Fill](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/editing/faces.html#grid-fill) which fills empty space with quads. Let me know if it helps.

Comment: Related, https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/84167/whats-the-fastest-way-to-turn-a-triangular-face-into-three-quads in that once a triangle is 3 quads, each quad can be broken down into more.  (still maintaining the 3 (edge) pole vert in the middle)

Comment: Thanks batFINGER! I'll try this and see if it's what I'm looking for.

Comment: Thank you ᴊᴀᴄʜʏᴍ ᴍɪᴄʜᴀʟ, but grid fill doesn't support closed edge loops. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Credit to batFINGER (in the comments): "Related, [What's the fastest way to turn a triangular face into three quads?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/84167/whats-the-fastest-way-to-turn-a-triangular-face-into-three-quads) in that once a triangle is 3 quads, each quad can be broken down into more. (still maintaining the 3 (edge) pole vert in the middle)"